# problem in array $_POST

Tags: php

i have this code it can go to `if(array_key_exists('p',$_POST))` but can't go to `if(isset($_POST['p'][$i]) && $_POST['p'][$i]==$row[0])`

i tried to `echo $_POST['p'][0]` in `if(array_key_exists('p',$_POST))` but it tells me 0 is undefined

i don't know my error.

```
if(array_key_exists('update',$_POST)){
//somecode
echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='p[$i]'  value='$row[0]' unchecked onclick='openinput()'/></td>";
if(array_key_exists('p',$_POST))
        {
        $result=mysql_query($query);        
        if($result)
        {
            $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($num>0)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['p'][$i]) && $_POST['p'][$i]==$row[0])
                {
                    foreach($_POST['p'] as $key=>$value)
                         {
                         //some code
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not lying i can show the whole code

Comment: i don't know that value=$row[0] or value='$row[0]' row[0] is integer it may be the error or not? i tried them too

Comment: i had changed my code my problem was solved there but for normalization I changed whole of my tables and now it has again error i tried the corrected one on that situation and updated it but the problem still is in it

Comment: Has 'p' been defined in a previous statement? I don't think so.
Which means in the 'echo' statement, name='p[$i]' should just be name='p[]'since 'p' is supposed to hold an array of values from checkboxes.

Comment: can you send the result of print_r($_POST) for your script ?

Comment: @lenzai, probably a var_dump($_POST) would be more useful.

Comment: afaolek I tested it in previous and it did work

Comment: lenzai it is the result:Array ( [p] => Array ( [7] => 1 ) [ph] => select please [update] => update [tx] => )

Comment: and it is from var_dump array(4) { ["p"]=> array(1) { [7]=> string(1) "1" } ["ph"]=> string(13) "select please" ["update"]=> string(6) "update" ["tx"]=> string(0) "" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following line gives problem

```
echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='p[$i]'  ...
```

Try this

```
echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='p[]'  ...
```

Comment: now it shows me some errors i think you are right because it can go to for each now and send me errors

Comment: Just a reminder: Actually it is beyond what u asked in this post already. If you have another problem you should do in another post :)